# Finding Factorials of a List of Numbers Python

Tags: python, factorial

I have a list of numbers [0,1,2,3,4,5,-1]

Trying to create a function to iterate through the list of numbers and find the factorials.

What I have is:

```
def factorial (n):
    fact = 1
    for number in range(1,item+1):
       fact = fact * number
    return factorial
```

For set:

```
my_numbs = [0,1,2,3,4,5,-1]
```

Then running the function:

```
factorial(my_numbs)
```

but it returns:

```
<function __main__.factorial>
```

The other issue is that I've got it to run in a for loop but it's saying the factorial of -1 is 1 but there isn't a factorial for -1 so it should return " "

Comment: in python you return the variable with the result 'return fact' not the function name.

Comment: What is `item` in the body of the function and why do you not use `n`?

Answer (score 0):

Your factorial function has no variable called `item` I think this is what you want:

```
def factorial (n):
    if n < 0:
        return "" #This is as per your specification
    fact = 1
    for number in range(1,n+1):
       fact = fact * number
    return fact
```

This function will give you the factorial of any number 'n'.
But you need the factorial of all elements in the list. So you can simply map the function to your list of numbers.

```
my_numbs = [0,1,2,3,4,5,-1]
result = list(map(factorial , my_numbs))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 problems.

1 Your function must return fact not factorial.

2 You call your function with a list 'my_numbs' but it expects an integer

3 You must iterate over my_numbs to implement 2

My guess: it looks like -1 is an 'end of list' indicator. In my example I end the iteration on this -1.

```
def factorial(n):
    fact = 1
    for number in range(1, n+1):
       fact = fact * number
    return fact

my_numbs = [0,1,2,3,4,5,-1]

index = 0
while True:
    if my_numbs[index] == -1:
        break

    print(factorial(my_numbs[index]))
    index += 1
```

Result

```
1
1
2
6
24
120
```